# React-native project Build failed: Could not find com.android.tools.lint , Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:lintVitalRelease'

Tags: android, react-native, build.gradle

I have some **troubles** trying to generate a release of my app.
App runs normally in emulator with `react-native run-android`.
when i try to run '`gradlew assembleRelease`' in android directory of my app, i get these :

> `D:\REACTNATIVE\finalprj\android>gradlew assembleRelease`
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> **What went wrong**:
>
> **Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:lintVitalRelease'.**
>
> **Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:lintClassPath'.**
>
> **Could not find com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle:26.4.2.**

```
 Searched in the following locations:
   - file:/C:/Users/Sam/.m2/repository/com/android/tools/lint/lint-gradle/26.4.2/lint-gradle-26.4.2.pom
   - file:/C:/Users/Sam/.m2/repository/com/android/tools/lint/lint-gradle/26.4.2/lint-gradle-26.4.2.jar
   - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/lint/lint-gradle/26.4.2/lint-gradle-26.4.2.pom
   - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/lint/lint-gradle/26.4.2/lint-gradle-26.4.2.jar
   - file:/D:/REACTNATIVE/finalprj/node_modules/react-native/android/com/android/tools/lint/lint-gradle/26.4.2/lint-gradle-26.4.2.pom
   - file:/D:/REACTNATIVE/finalprj/node_modules/react-native/android/com/android/tools/lint/lint-gradle/26.4.2/lint-gradle-26.4.2.jar
   - file:/D:/REACTNATIVE/finalprj/node_modules/jsc-android/dist/com/android/tools/lint/lint-gradle/26.4.2/lint-gradle-26.4.2.pom
   - file:/D:/REACTNATIVE/finalprj/node_modules/jsc-android/dist/com/android/tools/lint/lint-gradle/26.4.2/lint-gradle-26.4.2.jar
   - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/lint/lint-gradle/26.4.2/lint-gradle-26.4.2.pom
   - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/lint/lint-gradle/26.4.2/lint-gradle-26.4.2.jar
 Required by:
     project :app
```

build.gradle :

```
    // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 16
        compileSdkVersion = 28
        targetSdkVersion = 28
        supportLibVersion = "28.0.0"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath('com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2')
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenLocal()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android")
            
        }
        maven {
            // Android JSC is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
        }

        jcenter()
        google()
    }
}
```

Help me plz

any comments and suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to sign the [release APK](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/building-cmdline?hl=en#sign_cmdline) when you try to create it.

You can use `jarsigner` to sign an App Bundle from the command line. To sign APK instead, you must use `zipalign` and `apksigner` as follows:

1. In the `Androidstudio`, **select View > Tool Windows > Terminal** to
   open the command line and navigate to the directory where the
   unsigned APK is located.
2. Align the unsigned APK using `zipalign`:

```
zipalign -v -p 4 my-app-unsigned.apk my-app-unsigned-aligned.apk
```

3. Sign your APK with your private key using `apksigner`:

```
apksigner sign --ks my-release-key.jks --out my-app-release.apk my-app-unsigned-aligned.apk
```

4. Verify that your APK is signed:

```
apksigner verify my-app-release.apk
```

**Configure Gradle to sign your app**

Open the module-level `build.gradle` file and add the `signingConfigs {}` block with entries for `storeFile`, `storePassword`, `keyAlias` and `keyPassword`, and then pass that object to the signingConfig property in your build type. For example:

```
android {
    ...
    defaultConfig { ... }
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            // You need to specify either an absolute path or include the
            // keystore file in the same directory as the build.gradle file.
            storeFile file("my-release-key.jks")
            storePassword "password"
            keyAlias "my-alias"
            keyPassword "password"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much. \ (•◡•) /

Answer (score 1):

Add this into build.gradle inside the android {....}.

```
android{
....
lintOptions {
    checkReleaseBuilds false
    abortOnError false
}
}
```