# Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:lintVitalRelease' error on recent android upgrade 3.6.1

Tags: java, android-studio

Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:lintVitalRelease'.

> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:lintClassPath'.
>   Could not resolve com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle:26.6.1.
>        Required by:
>            project :app
>   No cached version of com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle:26.6.1 available for offline mode.
>   No cached version of com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle:26.6.1 available for offline mode.

Comment: try this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/57539977/8035260

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can try to add this code in your module.

```
lintOptions {

    checkReleaseBuilds false
    abortOnError false

}
```

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was the following; If you are using Android Studio 3.6.1 downgrade gradle to version 3.5.3:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3'
```

Then clean the project: **Build** > **Clean Project**.
Now I was able to run the project again. But if I rebuild the project, I got the same errors. I think there are some problems with the new Gradle offline mode integration in the new Android Studio version.